# How do I run a clojure file in a Linux pipe?

Tags: clojure

On a Linux system, I want to read some text and pass it as an argument to a Clojure file like this

```
cat ./some-text.txt | clj ./solution.clj
```

I would expect to see some output from Clojure printed to stdout. The solution.clj does not have the main function nor any namespace declared. I use deps.edn for my tooling. Is it even possible?

I have seen examples on SO from 9 years ago and the examples no longer work.

### some progress

I have this script where my file gives expected output, but I get a warning and I have no idea how to get rid of it.

### the script

```
#!/bin/bash

export OUTPUT_PATH=./out.txt
> ./out.txt
cat ./input0.txt | clj -Srepro ./solution.clj
cat ./out.txt
```

Part of the problem was the script expecting the environment variable to be set, which added complexity in my search for solution. In the script I have tried clojure and clj. Both give the warning.

### the warning

```
$ sh ./runme.sh 
WARNING: When invoking clojure.main, use -M
hello
```

How do I get rid of the warning if the script does not have the main function?

### the code

```
;; Complete the missingNumbers function below.

(defn missingNumbers [arr brr] (list "hello"))

(def fptr (get (System/getenv) "OUTPUT_PATH"))

(def n (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/trim (read-line))))

(def arr (vec (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" "))))

(def m (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/trim (read-line))))

(def brr (vec (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" "))))

(def result (missingNumbers arr brr))

(spit fptr (clojure.string/join " " result) :append true)
(spit fptr "\n" :append true)
```

Comment: @cfrick That doesn't look related at all to me?

Comment: @cfrick Ah, of course. Makes sense. I'll flag this comment thread for removal, since none of it is necessary anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `clojure` instead of `clj` if you don't need a REPL. Use `-M` for invoking `clojure.main` which you can then give the file argument:

```
cat ./some-text.txt | clojure -M ./solution.clj
```

Comment: It does not work. The warning is still there and the output is printed TWICE

Comment: repeated result comes from not clearing the out.txt, but the warning is still there

Comment: Please post the code of your program to make this problem reproducible.

Comment: you were close: cat ./input0.txt | clojure -Srepro -M ./solution.clj

Comment: getting rid of -Srepro makes the script fragment work as in your answer. thank you very much

Comment: Consider avoiding `cat`. `clojure -M ./solution.clj <./some-text.txt` provides the Java/Clojure runtime with a real, seekable file descriptor instead of a read-once FIFO (which also required running a separate process -- `/bin/cat` -- to spin up).